# VHDL how to make a process with sensitivity list wait?

Tags: vhdl

I'd like a process to listen to changes in a signal, but not before 20 ns. How can I achieve that?
It doesn't seem possible to use wait statements in such a process, which makes sense since is has a sensitivity list.
What I'm really trying to achieve is a test bench that changes one signal indefinitely and another for like 5 ns after signal ready = '1'. But I don't know precisely when that will happen. I only know that before 20 ns the system is still resetting and hence I should not listen to changes in ready before 20 ns because then I'd get errors.
Alternatives to the approach in the question are welcome.

Comment: `if ready = '1' and reset = '1'` is probably a good alternative to dictate what should be done in the first 20 ns

Comment: Run a fast clock.  Start incrementing a counter on ready.  Ignore changes to the other signal until the counter is high enough.

Comment: Perhaps you could do a little research on processes and wait statements.  A sensitivity list is the equivalent of placing a `wait on sensitivity_list; as the last statement in the process.  If a process sensitivity list and wait statements are mutually exclusive and the process with a sensitivity has an implied wait statement, why not make that explicit?

Comment: I interpreted the question as referring to `wait for 20ns` which obviously won't work in real hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For much testbench code, we do not use looping processes and process sensitivity lists to search for things.  Instead, we use wait to find events.

```
TestProc : process 
begin
  Out1 <= '1' ; -- Steady 1 after this point.

  -- Find Reset as it deactivates
  -- a better alternative than waiting for an ad-hoc amount of time
  if Reset /= ACTIVE then
    wait until Reset = ACTIVE ; 
  end if; 
  wait until Reset /= ACTIVE ; 

  -- find ready at a level 1
  if ready /= '1' then 
    wait until ready = '1' ; 
  end if ; 
  Out2 <= '1' after 5 ns ; 

  -- find a rising edge of Clock
  -- Assumes that clock always transitions from 0 to 1 
  wait until Clk = '1' ; 
  Out2 <= '0' after 5 ns ; 
  ...

  -- Also find a rising edge of Clock
  -- rising_edge is extra work for the simulator and probably not necessary here
  wait until rising_edge(Clk) ; 
  Out2 <= '1' after 5 ns ; 
  ...

  std.env.stop ; -- stop the testbench
end process TestProc ;
```

If you are looking for a behavioral model that drives Out1 to a static value, but inverts Out2 5 ns after each time Ready rises to a 1, then you can do the following:

```
signal Out2 : std_logic := '0' ; 
. . . 
FollowReady : process  
begin 
  -- initialization 
  Out1 <= '1' ; 
  wait for 20 ns ; 

  -- looping process like behavior
  loop 
    -- Ready is a design signal.  Only detect a 0 to 1 change
    wait until rising_edge(Ready) ;
    Out2 <= not Out2 after 5 ns ; 
  end loop ; 
end process ;
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a process with a sensitivity list and a wait statement, you can simply something like that :

**Method 1:**

Process 1 (No sensitivity list) containing the following:

```
Out1 <= '1';
wait for 20 ns;
Out1 <= '0';
wait;
```

Process 2 (The one with a sensitivity list) containing this:

```
if Ready = '1' then
  -- track signal changes
else
  -- stay idle
end if;
```

**Method 2:**

If your VHDL code is to be synthesized, I would try something different, also using two different processes.

It assumes that the changes on the signal you are tracking are not faster than your clock.

Process 1 detects changes on the signal:

```
edge_detector : process (Clk, Reset_n) 
    begin

    if Reset_n = '0' then  
        edge_detected <='0';
        old_s_signal <='0';  
    elsif rising_edge(Clk) then   
            if old_s_signal='1' and s_signal='0' then
                edge_detected<='1';
            else
                edge_detected<='0';
            end if; 
            old_s_signal<=s_signal;   
    end if;  
end process;
```

Process 2 waits for 20 ns and then takes actions when a change is seen on the signal:

```
tracker : process (Clk, Reset_n)   

variable cpt_wait : integer;  

begin

if Reset_n = '0' then 
    cpt_wait := '0';  
    -- initialize all other variables and signals assigned in this process here
elsif rising_edge(Clk) then   
        if cpt_wait = NB_OF_TCLK_TO_MAKE_20_NS then  
            if edge_detected = '1' then
                -- track changes    
            end if;
        else 
           cpt_wait := cpt_wait + 1;   
        end if;
 end if;   

end process;
```